# Toast is not working (react-toastify component)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

const handleResetPassword = async () => {
const email = emailRef.current.value;

```
    if (email) {
        await sendPasswordResetEmail(email);`enter code here`
        toast('Please!! Check Your Email');
    }
    else{
        toast('Please!! provide your email address');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and place code in `code` blocks properly.

Answer (score 1):

**import this**

```
import { ToastContainer ,toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";


const handleResetPassword = async () => { const email = emailRef.current.value;
    if (email) {
        await sendPasswordResetEmail(email);`enter code here`
        toast('Please!! Check Your Email');
    }
    else{
        toast('Please!! provide your email address');
    }
}
```

**call component  inside return method**

```
<ToastContainer />
```